# Docusign In session landing pages

Tags: docusignapi

i am assigning a redirect url in session landing pages feature of docu sign but it's not redirecting to this url after completion of signing process.
I think this is because of not activated session landing pages feature for my demo account, please help me to redirect to custom url after signing the document.

Comment: are you doing it for embedded signing or for remote signing?

Answer (score 0):

`In-Session` landing pages are needed for `embedded signers` only, but when you are using `remote signers` (i.e starting signing ceremony from the email) then you need to configure `Destination URLs` in the `branding`. [Branding - Destination URLs](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm) will give you details how to configure destination URLs at branding level for remote signers.

Comment: Thanks.Actually i configured branding too but not was default , now with default working.

Comment: Please, let me know how to hide No,Thanks link after docu sign finish button click.

Comment: I think hiding something is not related to this qs, so can you please open a new qs with the screenshot of the link what you want to hide? Also if this answer resolves your qs, please mark it as answered so that others can benefit from it.